# In R, how do I define a function which is equivalent to `deparse(substitute(x))`?

Tags: r, reflection, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

I want to write a function in R which grabs the name of a variable from the context of its caller's caller. I think the problem I have is best understood by asking how to compose `deparse` and `substitute`. You can see that a naive composition does not work:

```
# a compose operator
>  `%c%` = function(x,y)function(...)x(y(...))

# a naive attempt to combine deparse and substitute
> desub = deparse %c% substitute
> f=function(foo) { message(desub(foo)) }
> f(log)
foo

# this is how it is supposed to work
> g=function(foo) { message(deparse(substitute(foo))) }
> g(log)
log
```

I also tried a couple of variations involving `eval.parent` but with no luck. Any help is appreciated.

---

*Clarification*: I'm not looking for a synonym for `deparse(substitute(...))`, e.g. `match.call()[[2]]` - what I'm looking for is a way to define a function

```
desub = function(foo) {
    ...
    # What goes here?
}
```

such that the definition of `f` above produces the same answer as `g`. It should look like this:

```
> f=function(foo) { message(desub(foo)) }
> f(log)
log
```

Perhaps `match.call` could be of use in the body of `desub` above, but I'd like to know how. Thanks!

Comment: You can check `match.call`

Comment: @akrun: I know about `match.call` but I'm not seeing how it will help. Do you want to elaborate a little? Or maybe it will be easiest for you to just provide a line of code which does what I'm asking for...

Comment: I meant `g1 <- function(foo) match.call()[[2]];
g1(log)#log`

Comment: @akrun: Thank you, I added a clarification to the question so perhaps you can see better what I'm asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @egnha and @akrun for the brave attempts. After playing around a bit I found a solution that works.

This fragment:

```
desub <- function(y) {
  e1=substitute(y)
  e2=do.call(substitute,list(e1), env=parent.frame())
  deparse(e2)
}
```

gives:

```
> f <- function(x) message(desub(x))
> f(log)
log
```

---

Update:

With help from Mark Bravington on the R-devel list, I was able to generalize this to multiple frames. I thought I should post it here, because it's a bit more useful than the above, and because there was a tricky workaround involving (possibly buggy?) behavior in `parent.frame()`.

```
# desub(v,0)=="v"
# desub(v,1)==deparse(substitute(v))
# desub(v,2)==name of v in grandparent's frame
# etc.
desub = function(y,n=1) {
  env=environment();
  for(i in 0:n) {
    y = do.call(substitute, list(substitute(y)), env=env)
    env = do.call(my_mvb_parent, list(), env=env)
  }
  deparse(y)
}

# helper:
#
# - using mvb.parent.frame fixes problems with capture.output and
#   weird cycling behavior in the built-in parent.frame
#
# - this wrapper makes mvb.parent.frame not throw an error when we get
#   to globalenv()
my_mvb_parent=function() {
  library(mvbutils)
  tryCatch(
    mvb.parent.frame(2),
    error=function(e) { globalenv()})
}

if(1) {
  # example code
  g2=function(t) {
    for(i in 0:5) {
      res=desub(t,i);
      print(res);
      res1=capture.output(desub(t,i))
      stopifnot(capture.output(res)==res1)
    }
  }
  g1=function(z) g2(z)
  g=function(y) g1(y)
  g(log)
  # prints:
  ## [1] "t"
  ## [1] "z"
  ## [1] "y"
  ## [1] "log"
  ## [1] "log"
  ## [1] "log"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you surmised, this is an issue with environments. The reason why the function `f` does not give `log` when you call `f(log)`, is that the environment in which `substitute` is called, namely the evaluation environment of `desub`, does not contain a binding to `log`.

The remedy is to evaluate the call to `substitute` in the proper environment, and modify `desub` accordingly:

```
desub <- function(x, env = parent.frame()) {
  deparse(eval(substitute(substitute(x)), envir = env))
}
```

Now `f` does what it was intended to do:

```
f(log)
#> log
```

Comment: egnha: Thank you - before I accept it, do you mind editing your answer to supply the code for "# What goes here?"?

Comment: Also, your answer depends on the argument to `f_new` being named `x`. If you change it to `y`, then your program prints `x`...

Comment: @Metamorphic You're right. That behavior is consistent with the reasoning I gave. Nonetheless, your variation on my solution resolves the original problem setting more faithfully. I'll update.

Comment: Consistent? Yeah, once you edited your answer to fix the fact that your first argument to `desub` was unused, and then you looked at mine and realized that you needed to use `substitute` twice, then my answer started to look like a "variation on [your] solution"! heh... But now yours *is* a bit more concise. Although I don't see why you'd still want the second argument to your `desub`. Why not just `desub <- function(x) { deparse(eval.parent(substitute(substitute(x)))) }`? And my answer seems more intuitive to me. Not sure what's going on with `eval(substitute(substitute(x)))`. Curious.